# Formatar data Firebird SQL dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, data, firebird

Como converter uma data para o formato dd/mm/yyyy no Firebird ?

Tentei de alguns modos converter 2020/06/22 para o formato mas sempre saem no formato YYYY/MM/DD:

```
CONVERT(DATE, DATA, 103) AS "Data"
REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE, DATA, 1), '/', '') AS [DDMMYYYY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Os bancos de dados, não é exclusividade do firebird, armazenam as datas pela representação númerica, o tipo date no firebird armazena em um inteiro de 32bits, portanto o comportamento desejado depende de onde você ira manipular a data e não do Firebird.

```
select current_date as dataatual
, extract(week from current_date) as semana
, extract(weekday from current_date) as diasemana
, extract(day from current_date) as dia
, extract(month from current_date) as mes
, extract(year from current_date) as ano
, cast(current_date as char(10)) as formatoso
, extract(day from current_date) || '/'  || extract(month from current_date) || '/' || extract(year from current_date) as dataajustada
from rdb$database
```